# Импортирование проекта в eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Всем привет!

Никогда не работал с проектами, которые содержат библиотеки. Поэтому появился вопрос. У меня есть исходники проекта. В этом проекте используется к примеру библиотека ActionBarSherlock.
Как этот проект импортировать в eclipse ? Я делаю, как обычно file ->import. После этого открывается основной проект и проект библиотеки отдельно и оба в ошибках. Подскажите, пожалуйста как правильно делать импорт проектов с библиотеками.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOB72vWY_5s советую посмотреть